# Where to pick up/drop off passengers in Toronto airport?

Tags: yyz

Can cars drive on the Ground level of Pearson Terminal 1 in Toronto Ontario  or is that level only for buses, taxis, and airport shuttles?

Comment: if this is about picking up an arriving passenger, see: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40254/where-to-pick-up-arriving-passengers-at-terminal-1-toronto-pearson-intll-airpo

Answer (score 3):

Pearson Terminal 1, like all the terminals, has places where individuals can drop or pick up other people. They are the same places where taxis and busses drop and pick up people, right outside the departures/arrivals entrance.

If you are dropping, you can simply drive to the 'departures' area, stop briefly, let the person out and drive away. You will be right there with the taxis and limos.

If you are picking up, the only complication is that you are not allowed to wait in that area. What most private individuals do is to park in the short term parking (which of course costs money) and walk to arrivals, where you pick up your friend and walk back to the car. Alternatively you can wait in the free [cell phone parking lot](https://www.torontopearson.com/en/Cell_Phone_Lot/##) (thanks Michael Hampton), have them call you when they are completely ready to be picked up, arrange an exact point to meet at arrivals, and then drive in to pick them up while they wait. If you need to do this because the person you are picking up has difficulty walking, check to see if the airport will provide special services for them.

Comment: You can load in the middle lanes in arrivals, but it's usually jampacked with cars. If you go this way, you'll want to wait in the cell phone lot until the person you're picking up has exited the building and calls you.

Comment: Is the cell phone lot available to the public? I thought it was limos only.

Comment: Yes, they are open to everyone [specifically for waiting for an arriving passenger](https://www.torontopearson.com/en/Cell_Phone_Lot/#). They are also free parking.